# Append the column names corresponding to the minimum row values of a dataframe to create a new dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[5,4,3,2,6,8], [9,1,5,4,8,6], [7,6,8,1,2,4], [9,6,5,4,8,3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col6'])
df
```

I am trying to display the minimum value of each row along with the column name.

```
df=df.min(axis=1)
df
```

output:

```
2
1
1
3
```

But how can I append the column names corresponding to those minimum value of rows?

My expected output is

```
2    col4
1    col2
1    col4
3    col6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
df[['Col', 'Value']] = df.apply(lambda x: [idx:=x.idxmin(), x[idx]], axis=1, result_type='expand')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6   Col  Value
0     5     4     3     2     6     8  Col4      2
1     9     1     5     4     8     6  Col2      1
2     7     6     8     1     2     4  Col4      1
3     9     6     5     4     8     3  Col6      3
```

---

If you want only the `Col`, `Value`:

```py
print(df[['Col', 'Value']].set_index('Value'))
```

Prints:

```
        Col
Value      
2      Col4
1      Col2
1      Col4
3      Col6
```